# Python on android

Tags: android, python, pygame, kivy

Besides the official pygame port to android which requires python 2.7.1 which I like 3.4.1 better. Also besides Kivy, what is a way to put pygame or another python module on android?

Comment: http://pygame.renpy.org/android-packaging.html

Comment: Thanks, i guess ill just have to rewrite to work in 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for ways of running Python on Android, I'd use [Android Scripting](https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a). It provides support for python 2.x and exposes API's for calling hardware features on your droid. Note it is in an early state of development so I wouldn't use it for anything in production.

Comment: Hm. Would i be able to just use it in a prewritten python program by adding a couple of things it needs?

Comment: So it's designed to allow a more native experience by allowing you to embed a fully functional python interpreter within an Android environment. Unfortunately this does require a working understanding of both Java and Android's framework.

You can also try downloading an app called [SL4A Script Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.androidideas.scriptlauncher) which allows you to select a python module to launch from your memory card.